# How to: Multiple colored plot lines plus two y-axis in R

Tags: r, plot, colors, axis

I'm new to R and I haven't got a single clue, let that be stated first.

I have a csv file saved to `data` with the header `Cycle,Instances,MaxFitness,MinFitness`
where cycle just numbers the lines, the instances go over a sinus between 0 and 100 and the fitness values are between 0.5 and 5.

The desired output is a single svg or pdf file, where I have the cycles on the x axis, the fitness on the left y axis and the instances on the right y axis. In addition to that, I need an individually colored plot-line for min, max and the instances.

I've been messing around with plot, xyplot and so on for a while now but something is usually missing something, let it be "color", "all in one diagramm" and stuff like that.

If someone could shed some light on this issue, that'd be awesome.

Comment: I think the quickest workaround is to use basic plot with normalised data and then add manually the y axis accordingly

Comment: Can you give us your `head(data)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did with the package `plotly`.

Here is the code (my data is not according to your description, but it is enough for showing the code).

```
library("plotly")

set.seed(123)

df <- data.frame(
  Cycle=c(1:10)
  , Instances=runif(10,0,100)
  , MaxFitness=runif(10,0.5,5)
  , MinFitness=runif(10,0.5,5)
)


######
## Plot
p <- plot_ly(data = df) %>%
  add_lines(x=~Cycle, y=~MaxFitness, color="blue", name="MaxFitness") %>%
  add_lines(x=~Cycle, y=~MinFitness, color="green", name="MinFitness") %>%
  add_lines(x=~Cycle, y=~Instances, color="red", name="Instances", yaxis="y2") %>%

  layout(

    title = "Double Y Axis Example",
    yaxis=list(
      title = "left y axis"
    ),
    yaxis2=list(
      tickfont = list(color = "red"),
      overlaying = "y",
      side = "right",
      title = "right y axis"
    )

  )
p
```

Here's the output:
[image]

Now you can edit your whole plot based on your preference.

Answer (score 0):

Without any MWE, I have created one:

```
# Create two series with different scales
# Your Cycle is then the index, from 1 to 20
x1 = runif(20, 0, 100)
x2 = runit(20, 0.5, 5)
# Plot them and add specific y axis
plot(x1/100, type ="l", yaxt ="n", ylab ="", ylim = c(0,1))
lines((x2-0.5)/4.5, col = 2)
axis(side = 2, at = c(0.2, 0.8), labels = c(20, 80))
axis(side = 4, at = c(0.5), labels = c(2.75))
```

And so result is[image]